# How to install play2War plugin (Play Framework 2.2.3)

Tags: java, playframework-2.2

I'd be very grateful if someone could provide me the basic steps to install the Play2War Plugin. Like where to put the plugin files?, and which files?

I'm pretty new with Play Framework (Java), just created my first application, and want to deploy it on my server, 
 but unfortunately I found out that the 2.x version didn't have the built in war command anymore.
 I scoured the documentation and found the links Configuration, Usage and Deployment, but what I want to know are the steps until get there. My application is created in 
play 2.2.3

Comment: Which ide you are using

Comment: @Orion eclipse helios